# LEGO bionicle identification

Tags: set-identification, bionicle

We randomly saw this creature on a Google search for "vahki" creatures. but we can't find it again and we didn't click through and find a number.

[image: some vahki creature]

Can anyone identify this being?

Answer (score 3):

Not an official LEGO set, that's for sure. As far as I can tell, it's an inspirational model for a building contest a few years back, constructed by [John Ho](https://www.flickr.com/photos/iced_coffee/15533419950/in/photostream/).

Comment: heh! great. my eight year old saw it and now dearly wants to build it! any tips on assembling spare pieces? we are relatively new bionicle fans. thanks for the help! my phone can't view flicker, but I'll look when I'm on the pc.

Comment: @hazmatrec The number one way I've built up my collection is through craigslist posting of large lots of LEGO. If you're looking for pieces on the cheap, that would be the best way to go. As for brainstorming ideas, it's really just a matter of seeing what can fit where. If you're looking for inspiration, there are many LEGO builders on MOCpages and DeviantArt with... varying levels of skill, that you can pull concepts from and adapt or modify as needed.